# How to get the node with certain text value in xpath?

Tags: xpath, scrapy

I have a very long website with many script nodes, how can I access to the one that has 'var config' in the text with xpath?

```
<script>
    var config = {
        locale: 'es',
        userAuthenticated: false
}
<script>
```

Comment: Do you mean this is the only `script` element having `var congif` attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case this is the only node with `script` tag name having `config` attribute you can use the following XPath to locate it:

```
"//script[@config]"
```

In case there is some unique value inside the `config` values, like `userAuthenticated` here XPath like this could be used:

```
"//script[contains(@config,'userAuthenticated')]"
```

**UPD**
The element you are looking for can be located with the following XPath:

```
"//script[contains(.,'userAuthenticated')]"
```

Comment: Yes, but not getting any answer, this is what the selector looks like in my terminal <Selector xpath='//script' data="<script>\n\tvar config = {\n\t\tlocale: 'e...">

Comment: What you wrote here looks far different from what I mentioned. I'm even not sure your expression is valid..

Comment: Can you share a link to the page you are working on and clarify what element are you trying to locate there?

Comment: https://www.idealista.com/inmueble/96423734/
I want to get all the images urls. However, the format of the data is different in the request and in the web html

Comment: Now I see. Please see my updated answer. It uniquely locates that element.

Comment: Yes, this works. How do you get the '.'?
Many thanks for your time, I really appreciate it!

Comment: A dot '.' here means any attribute